# Location service deosn't return the current location on ice cream sanwditch

Tags: android, location, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i'm developing an application that gets the current user location .. my code works fine on jillybean, kitkat, lollipop .. but on ice cream sandwitch it returns my last location not my current location 
and here is my code

```
 public void getLocation() {
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    for (String provider : providers) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
                new LocationListener() {
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        Globals.latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        Globals.longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    }

                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                            int status, Bundle extras) {
                    }
                });
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider
                    + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                System.out.println("Provider " + provider
                        + " has been selected.");
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            Globals.latitude = -1;
            Globals.longitude = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code what have you done?

Comment: Maybe GPS is just turned off?

Comment: ICS some issue with location services I am also looking for a solution for this